# Toggling preventDefault() On mouseover and mouseleave of Parent Container

Tags: javascript, events, mouseevent

I have some containers that have child containers inside which contain links.

What happens is when the user hovers over the parent container to show the child, the links are disabled for the first 2 seconds. If a user moves the mouse away before clicking the link this behaviour is reset with a 'hasBeenHovered' variable that changes from true to false inside the mouseleave event.

The two issues I'm facing are:

a) I can't get it to work solely on the parent being hovered - it loops through all of them and shows them all;

b) On mobile is there anyway of returning the opacity to 1 and disabling the links again by re-tapping (so the re-tap effectively works as the mouseleave event?). If this is very complex to do I may just have it so it stays visible until the parent container hits the top of the viewport.

Although the code sandbox is below it says "Uncaught TypeError: allowLinks is not a function", yet on CodePen the demo works?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Emily

CodePen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/rNjXMee

```js
var parent = document.querySelectorAll(".parent");
var child = document.querySelectorAll(".child");
var link = document.querySelectorAll(".link");

var hasBeenHovered = false;

var listener = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
};

// prevent default on all specific links
link.forEach(function (item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", listener);
});

// mouseover that changes opacity to 1 and removes prevent default on links
parent.forEach(function (item) {
  item.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
      child.forEach(function (item) {
        item.style.opacity = "1";
        item.style.transition = "opacity .5s";
      });

      // remove prevent Default
      if (hasBeenHovered === false) {
        function allowLinks() {
          link.forEach(function (item) {
            item.removeEventListener("click", listener);
            hasBeenHovered = true;
          });
        }
      }

      setTimeout(function () {
        allowLinks();
      }, 2000);
    
    }, false );
  
});

// mouseleave event re-adds opacity: 0 and re-adds prevent default
parent.forEach(function (item) {
  item.addEventListener("mouseleave", function (event) {
      child.forEach(function (item) {
        item.style.opacity = "0";
        item.style.transition = "opacity .5s";
      });

      // re-add prevent Default
      if (hasBeenHovered === true) {
        link.forEach(function (item) {
          item.addEventListener("click", listener);
          hasBeenHovered = false;
        });
      }
    }, false );
  
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.child {
  opacity: 0; /* hides child container*/
  padding: 1rem;
  background: red;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com" class="link">This will work after 2 seconds of mouseover</a>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com" class="link">This will work after 2 seconds of mouseover</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com" class="link">This will work after 2 seconds of mouseover</a>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com" class="link">This will work after 2 seconds of mouseover</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to keep most of your original code logic, I've modified quite a bit of it but this should be what your are aiming for. For the mobile part I'd recommend a flag for the touch handler, but do note it'll get a bit more complicated since mobile also responds to the `onclick` handlers.

The links will not work in the snippet due to StackOverflow security so added a console log but will work if you copy to CodePen

```js
const parents = document.querySelectorAll(".parent");

parents.forEach(parent => {
  const children = parent.querySelectorAll(".child");
  const links = parent.querySelectorAll(".link");

  let timeoutId = null; // track the timeout so we can clear it
  let enableLinks = false; // should we allow links?

  links.forEach(link =>
    link.addEventListener("click", evt => {
      if (!enableLinks) {
        evt.preventDefault(); // hold them hostage
      } else {
        console.log('StackOverflow prevents links'); // just a placeholder for SO snippet
      }
    }, true)
  );

  parent.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    enableLinks = false; // ensure links are disabled at first
    children.forEach(child => child.style.opacity = "1"); // let the children be seen
    if (!timeoutId) // make sure there isn't already a timeout
      timeoutId = setTimeout(() => enableLinks = true, 2000); // enable links after the 2s
  }, false);

  parent.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
    children.forEach(child => child.style.opacity = "0"); // hide your children
    clearTimeout(timeoutId); // remove the timeout so it can't overlap
    timeoutId = null; // clear timeout id
    enableLinks = false; // turn off links
  }, false);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.child {
  opacity: 0;
  /* hides child container*/
  padding: 1rem;
  background: red;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com" class="link">This will work after 2 seconds of mouseover</a>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com" class="link">This will work after 2 seconds of mouseover</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com" class="link">This will work after 2 seconds of mouseover</a>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com" class="link">This will work after 2 seconds of mouseover</a>
  </div>
</div>
```